# How to get Oauth 2 token and sign in UCWA and use Skype Web SDK

Tags: azure, oauth, skype, skype-for-business, ucwa

For use ucwa, I take purchased account in Skype for Business, admin panel to Office 365, access to Azure AD, but why all this? I want to make web page chat for skype, using ucwa. Or I do not need it all?

Why when i used url

`https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize` or  `https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/WebTicket/oauthtoken` for post request i recieve

> unsupported_grant_type password

why for `client_id="00000004-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000"` i have error

> No reply address is registered for the application

Please help me.

Comment: show us some code, or read the oath2 spec, you probably missing parameters.

Comment: ok, this my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868433/how-to-get-authorization-to-ucwa-and-skype-web-sdk

Comment: Don't post the same basic question again. That makes this a duplicate, with less detail.

Comment: sorry, i remove my duplicate post

Comment: UCWA isn't available in Office 365 yet.