# How to log in to UCWA using a passive grant type?

Tags: http, web, saml, ws-federation, ucwa

I have account in Skype for Bussiness with user@domain access.
My first request to lyncdiscover receive to me a json answer

```html
GET https://lyncdiscover.shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com/

{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?originalDomain=shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "user": {
      "href": "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "xframe": {
      "href": "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html"
    }
  }
}
```

In next do request to `user` link

```html
GET https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com

Answer:
Cache-Control → no-cache
Content-Length → 1293
Content-Type → text/html
Date → Fri, 02 Oct 2015 12:47:08 GMT
WWW-Authenticate → Bearer 
trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", 
client_id="00000004-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", 
authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", 
MsRtcOAuth 
href="https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/WebTicket/oauthtoken",
grant_type="urn:microsoft.rtc:passive,urn:microsoft.rtc:anonmeeting"
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff
X-MS-Correlation-Id → 2147515548
X-MS-Server-Fqdn → AMS1E01EDG04.infra.lync.com
client-request-id → eb37ab92-78a7-4f47-bc79-2d1fcad90b99
```

Server return only `urn:microsoft.rtc:passive` and `urn:microsoft.rtc:anonmeeting`, not `password`.

Ok, i,m try to do this use `urn:microsoft.rtc:passive`:

```html
POST https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/WebTicket/oauthtoken

grant_type=urn:microsoft.rtc:passive

Answer:
Content-Length → 1293
Content-Type → text/html
Date → Fri, 02 Oct 2015 13:05:11 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff
X-MS-Correlation-Id → 2147515642
X-MS-Server-Fqdn → AMS1E01EDG02.infra.lync.com
X-Ms-diagnostics → 
28048;source="AMS1E01EDG02.infra.lync.com";
reason="The user is not signed in with WS Federation Passive credentials."
client-request-id → b4a39398-0089-44f6-bdfb-768902f7289d

Answer body:
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the 
credentials that you supplied
```

The user is not signed in with WS Federation Passive credentials. How to get this credentials?

Comment: This is repeated question you can check here answer [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868433/how-to-get-authorization-to-ucwa-and-skype-web-sdk)

Comment: That answer is not full and specifically does not work. About current question - it more revealing

Comment: Did you get any solution Artem?

Comment: my solution is use [web skype api](http://web.skype.com/) instead ucwa. 
Its not official, but despite this, it is better than ucwa